# Can we apply @FunctionalInterface annotation to abstract classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop, java-8, functional-programming, functional-interface

I know it can be applied on **interface** but as Interfaces with default methods ( Java 8+ Interfaces ) are very close now to abstract classes, Just wondering now can we use **@FunctionalInterface with Abstract classes**?

If not why we can't?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: as appear its name it uses just for interfaces. and you can test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is use of Functional Interface in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8)

Comment: No, FI was solely created to facilitate lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

You can not apply `@FunctionalInterface` to abstract class, enum or another annotation. From [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> If a type is annotated with this annotation type, compilers are required to generate an error message unless:
>
> - The type is an interface type and not an annotation type, enum, or class.
> - The annotated type satisfies the requirements of a functional interface.

See more [Abstract class as functional interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610207/abstract-class-as-functional-interface)

Comment: Any reason why we cant?

Comment: @PraJazz see here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610207/abstract-class-as-functional-interface

Answer (score 1):

As the name indicates it should be used for interfaces. Applying it to class results in the following:

> Error:(10, 1) java: Unexpected @FunctionalInterface annotation
>     xxx is not a functional interface

But this is not much of a problem, as this is just a marker interface for interfaces with one method.

Answer (score -2):

The functional interface is there for the specific purpose - 
It's used with interfaces only which have strictly one and only one abstract method.
if not then the compiler complains -

```
Invalid '@FunctionalInterface' annotation; TestInterface is not a functional interface
```

[image: Eclipse showing error]

And there is no point in using this with any other class, enum stuffs